# Get a name from a database using the id of the same row. In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im very new to php and i want to try and get a name from a database by using the id number.
Eg id=1 name=test
i want to say when id=1 make name=test
I thought this would do it, I have been trying make up the php myself. Rather than follow specific tutorials. Im assuming what i want to do is very commonly done but i cant understand where my code is going wrong.

```
$id = "1"; // later i will add it so this is defined by the link you click on
$firstname = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM $info_table WHERE id = $id");
$secondname = mysql_query("SELECT secondname FROM $info_table WHERE id = $id"); 
$name = $firstname $secondname;`
echo name;
```

the table is $info_table and then the firstname and secondname parts are the columns. Is that how it should be or not?

Anyone help clear up my confusion.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can select a number of fields from your table with a single query, like so:

```
$records = mysql_query("SELECT `firstname`, `lastname` from `$info_table` WHERE id = $id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)) {
     echo "Name: $firstname $lastname";
}
```

However, please keep in mind that the `mysql` set of functions are deprecated, meaning if you use them, your code will likely **not work** in future versions of PHP. So to ensure your code is future proof, I would look into the mysqli* set of functions, or PDO.

One final thing, the code you have provided above provides NO protection against SQL injection, this is important if you are accepting any values from the user to be used in SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the records by doing this:

```
$firstname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $info_table WHERE id = $id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstname)) {
echo $row['firstname'] . $row['secondname'];
}
```

Comment: Except the select * which is not efficient, mysql_query is to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*.

If you are going to do this staticly then Moeed Farooqui answer is ok, but if you are looking for dynamically the you have to make id dynamically generated on any event.

for example link(as you say):

```
<a href="yourlink.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">click</a>
```

and then get this id on yourlink.php and your code look like as:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$firstname = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM $info_table WHERE id = $id");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($firstname);
echo $row['firstname'];
```